# Messages being sent multiple times on Android

Tags: java, android, sms

I'm currently using this bit of code to send messages:

```
        SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();

        ArrayList<String> parts = sm.divideMessage(M.getString("Content"));

        deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++)
        {
            sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Integer.parseInt(M.getString("ID")), new Intent(SMS_SEND_ACTION), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT));
            deliveryIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Integer.parseInt(M.getString("ID")), new Intent(SMS_DELIVERY_ACTION), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT));
        }

        sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(M.getString("Number"),null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents);
```

Most of the times the message I’m trying to send is received by the recipient multiple times and I can not figure out why.

I've used log cat and I'm sure I am not calling the code twice.

Comment: Don't use logcat, it's for logging not debugging (in general).  Put a breakpoint on the first line you have shown and step through the code.

Comment: `multiple times` - how many exactly? Also, which method is the above code located in - please show the whole method code. Also, use SmsManager from android.telephony (if using android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager, which was deprecated in API 4)